# Bind two columns values in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I Developed Online Appointment application using asp.net,c# and sql server. 
 I want to bind the two column in that dropdown.
In my database table have two column of MobileNo ,LandNo.
I want these two columns value come in a single dropdown using C# and asp.net.
Ex:

```
Mobileno:97456874532,7523684521
Landno:0886075123,0886035123
```

Result in Dropdown:

```
97456874532
7523684521
0886075123
0886035123
```

Comment: which _version_ of sql are you using ?

Comment: You may need to union those two columns, Query: select Mobileno as TeleNumber from table union all select Landno from table.

Comment: Thanks Manivannam.  It's Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of customization you want to do for this you need to concate value of columns in sql query or you can do it in code once you get collection.

```
public class ContactNumber
{
  public string MobileNo {get;set;}
  public string LandNo {get; set;}
  public string ContacNo { get {retun MobileNo +','+ LandNo;}}
}
```

now get the list of all from database

```
List<ContactNumber> contacno = = new List<ContactNumber>()
    {
        new ContactNumber(){ MobileNo  = 1, LandNo  = "Jessica"},
        new ContactNumber(){ MobileNo  = 2, LandNo  = "Mandy"}
    };
```

than assign this list of you dropdown i.e. bind ContactNo property to your DataTextField property of dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Pranay Rana,  Thanks for sharing your valuable information

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple I will not create a custom type rather rely on a buil-in type like `int` or `string` (whatever suits your need). Here I am considering mobile & phone no.'s are intergers and will add them in the ADO.NET code like this:-

```
public List<int> GetContactInfo()
{
    List<int> contacts = new List<int>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Mobileno,Landno FROM Demo", conn))
       {
           conn.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                  contacts.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Mobileno"]));
                  contacts.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Landno"]));
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

Then simply add this datasource to your dropdown:-

```
myDropdown.DataSource = GetContactInfo();
myDropdown.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul Singh. It's Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are binding the column(mobile no) from database directly to the list. If you do like that, only that column values are bind to the list.

If you want to bind two or more column values(even including your custom string), you need to manage that in "OnItemBound" event of the dropdown list.

In "OnItemBound" event evluate the two column values and make a string using these evaluated values, then assign the newly constructed string to the list item.

It will look like this

Item.text = "Mobileno : " + Eval("Mobileno").ToString() + "," + Eval("Landno").ToString();

I will explain clearly, if u post the code you written.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your valuable information. I used Collection list . It's working fine . I will try your code also. Thanks lot.